# I need to use the user selected data across multiple pages, which module can i use Session or Cookie

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.6 framework to build an E-commerce website,
so i need to use the user searched data across multiple pages, also
for the current page even after the page reload ,
My data flow is : -

1. search the product
2. select the product and add to cart
3. checkout the product

   Help me guys , Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. you could use **session**, as it persist across requests. cookies will be sent to end user and they might edit the cookie by themselves if you are not careful.

Comment: how much time a session lasts

Comment: should be in your `config` folder in `session.php`. see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#configuration).